# Is there a way to avoid having to "colcon build" every time I edit Python code?

Tags: ros, ros2, python3, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Dashing of ROS2. I am using Python Code.
Every time I edit the python code in the node file, I do a "colcon build".
Is there a way to avoid having to "colcon build" every time, even when editing python code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379726/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-having-to-%22colcon-build%22-every-time-i-edit-python-code?/) by [sansevieria22](https://answers.ros.org/users/75265/sansevieria22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, use a *symlinked install*.

See #q371822 and [Colcon - build - Build Packages](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/build.html):

> `--symlink-install`
>
> Use symlinks instead of copying files from the source and build directories where possible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sansevieria22](https://answers.ros.org/users/75265/sansevieria22/) on 2021-06-07**:
very nice! Thank you very much!